# LWUIT list items

Tags: list, java-me, lwuit

i need to add in list components that are not equal in height, is there a way for it to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the ContainerList class which is a part of LWUIT 1.5 and [Codename One](http://www.codenameone.com/).

Answer (score 1):

Different cell heights within a list are not supported by LWUIT. The list takes care and resizes all cells to the size of the largest one.
Thought about different renderers (e.g. fisheye renderer [link](http://lwuit.blogspot.com/2008/07/lwuit-list-renderer-by-chen-fishbein.html)) for different components if you need to alter , even thought the cell height stays the same for the whole list.

Answer (score 0):

You can use your component which extends from container and add those components in a Container which has BoxLayout.Y axis as its layout so that all the list items will have height according to the text that you added. How many items do you want to add?